# Combinatorics Proof: Binomial Coefficient is always odd

Tags: combinatorics, induction

Let $k$ and $m$ be positive integers such that $1 \leq m \leq 2^k - 1$.

Prove that the binomial coefficient $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 2^k-1 \\ m \end{array}\right)$ is odd.

Comment: **Hint:** [Lucas' Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem)$$\binom{2^k-1}{m}\equiv\prod_{r=0}^{k-1}\binom 1{m_r}\equiv\ldots\pmod 2$$ where the $m_r$'s are the binary digits of $m$ which can either be $0$ or $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Pascal's triangle modulo 2 and the result ${n-1\choose k-1}+{n-1\choose k}={n\choose k}$. The triangle normally looks like this:

$n=0: 1$

$n=1: 1\ 1$

$n=2: 1\ 2\ 1$

$n=3: 1\ 3\ 3\ 1$

$n=4: 1\ 4\ 6\ 4\ 1$

$n=5: 1\ 5\ 10\ 10\ 5\ 1$

Modulo 2 (which just means $1$ if something's odd and $2$ if it is even) the triangle looks like this:

$n=0: 1$

$n=1: 1\ 1$

$n=2: 1\ 0\ 1$

$n=3: 1\ 1\ 1\ 1$

$n=4: 1\ 0\ 0\ 0\ 1$

$n=5: 1\ 1\ 0\ 0\ 1\ 1$

From here, you should be able to spot a pattern which shouldn't be too difficult to prove rigorously.